# How to add username field to devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Here is what I tried,

1. `rails g migration add_username_to_hrs`
2. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
3. added the `attr_accessible:username`
4. restarted the server

**My add_username_to_hr.rb**

```
class AddUsernameToAuthorize < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    add_column :authorizes, :username, :string
 end
end
```

**Error**

> undefined method `username' for #

**Question**: How can I add a username field in my devise gem?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have an input field for username in the login form when using devise?

Comment: steps are right. what problem is occur when you start server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Answer is now outdated [ Valid for rails4 ]**

I have done the same. Please follow these steps:

1. `rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq`
2. `rake db:migrate`
3. add `attr_accessible :username`
4. in application_controller.rb:

   ```
   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

   protected
   def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
   end
   ```
5. in config/initializers **if you want to replace `email` by `usernname`**

   ```
   config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
   config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]  
   config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
   ```
6. update the views.

**Note** if `attr_accessible :username`gives error try `attr_accessor :username`

Comment: Beware rails 5 users, this answer is now outdated. Follow the wiki link provided by @Jakob W. [Here it is too](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address), just in case.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using rails 4 then put below code in application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using rails 4 then follow this steps:

1. `rails g migration AddUserNameToAuthorize`
2. `rake db:migrate`
3. put this code in `application_controller.rb` to accept username parameter for `sign_in`, `sign_up` and also for `account_update`:

   ```
   class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
       protect_from_forgery with: :exception
       def configure_permitted_parameters
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password,:username) }
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username) }
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation,:username) }
       end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Devise actually add the field to model which you specified during devise setup. If You have add migration to that model. For example, you have used devise for user model, then you can generate migration for adding the username to user model and run the db:migrate and add the attr_accessible :username to model, if you are using rails < 4

Answer (score 2):

You have to add username in the model which you had given in below command

```
rails g devise <modelname>
```

Once you are done then you need to follow your above steps but need to modify devise configuration file to look for username for login instead of email. Then restart rails server and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

source = https://github.com/heartcombo/devise

add username to your usermodel
`db:migrate`

and then past following in your ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
  end
end
```

also this in your devise/registration/new.html.erb into the

```
  <%= f.input :username,
              required: true,
              autofocus: true,
              input_html: { autocomplete: "username" }%>
```

and you're good to go

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help