# Returning User name into form when registration failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Sorry for my english, it will hard to describe problem. I have user devise model with registration params [:name, :email, :password, :confirm_password] . Problem is in name field. For example if registration was failed because of mismatched password RAILS render new reg. form but name field will be  empty, but i need to set it by previous value. Email filed sets good, because it is a default param of devise gem. Can some one help?

Comment: Would this question give you the hints you need?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478006/how-to-add-username-field-to-devise-gem

Comment: Please provide your view file