# Need help in rails devise registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

hey guys i want to register a new user with the help of devise but the view containes only 2 fields which are email and the password

i wish to save name, address, city, etc which are in my users table as well. In the view of registration/new.html.erb

after i added them in the view and i clicked sign up the following errors showed up

5 errors prohibited this user from being saved:

```
Name can't be blank
City can't be blank
Address can't be blank
Country can't be blank
Postal code can't be blank
```

so can someone please tell me what do i have to do to make devise accept these additional atrributes aside from email and password and save them in my users table

Comment: you will get answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478006/how-to-add-username-field-to-devise-gem/21478201#21478201

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your `ApplicationController` to let Devise permit parameters other than `email` and `password`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    permitted_params = %i(name city address country postal) # returns [:name, :city, :address, :country, :postal]

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: permitted_params)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: permitted_params)
  end
end
```

This way, you're configuring devise to permit the additional fields on both new account registration and profile updation.

For more, read https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters